# Floating shelve bracket in drywall

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I’ve purchase [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R1H8BXY) brackets and only realised later that there is only 1 stud where I want to install the floating shelve. Is it possible to install these screws/brackets into a drywall? If so, which drywall plug should I use? I’m not too converned about weight as the shelf will mainly hold small decorative items.

Answer (score 3):

The product you've linked appears to include drywall anchors, circled in red in this screenshot:
[image: "floating" shelf brackets with plug-type anchors]

This plug-type anchor is not very sturdy in drywall (it's a lot better in brick or concrete), and for most purposes I prefer not to use them, especially where there's some torque acting on the anchor as is the case with a cantilevered shelf. However, apparently the manufacturer thinks they're up to the task at least for light loads. When drilling the hole for the anchor, be extra careful to keep it perpendicular to the wall and to not make it oversized (should be a *snug* fit for the anchor before the screw is installed).

Alternatively you could discard the plug anchors that come with the brackets and use  something like this instead:

[image: ez-ancor brand screw-type drywall anchors]

But you might have to look around to find one that works well with the screw thread on the end of the brackets.

Comment: I wouldn’t have thought that those plugs are suitable for drywalls. The shank for the screws is 7mm. Would that fit the drywall plugs you recommended? I only ever used this type with smaller screws.

Comment: @orange that plug design is pretty much [the original drywall anchor](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/09/business/international/artur-fischer-inventor-with-more-patents-than-edison-dies-at-96.html). But yeah, whether it's actually suitable for its intended purpose is debatable.

Comment: you problem is that's a cantilevered load.  I have never had luck with a drywall anchor with such a load.  The weight is a lever trying to pull the anchor out of the wall.

Comment: @TigerGuy I think you’ve got a point there. Even with little load the weight of the shelf itself will probably pull the screw out. I might cut the drywall open and support it with a piece of wood across. Was really hoping to avoid that.